# How to keep assigned SAS user promts from disappearing after you sign out of SAS?

Tags: sas, prompt

I have successfully assigned user prompts by:

right clicking on the program -> properties -> prompts -> Prompt Manager

and adding what I want the user to edit when the run button is pushed. What I have not yet discovered is how to keep those prompt assignments after I exit SAS. When I reopen the program the prompts are gone/blank. I understand that I need to edit the program file in which I want to use a prompt. The prompt should be added to the code as &prompt-name. But I have not yet found code or examples on how to do this. Can anybody help?

Comment: What client are you using?  I THINK you are using Enterprise Guide.  Which version?

Comment: Enterprise Guide 4.3.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to that version.  It works OK in the 2 versions I do have.  I would open a tech support issue with SAS.  http://support.sas.com